# I got scammed or not and what should I do?

Tags: online-payment

One day a company send me email that I was selected for position of assistant in real state agent. Then filled up form and ready for 1 month paid trial. Then they send me email to contact a person via telegram and contacted and gave me several task and also let me open bitcoin account. As instructed I did all. One day the task was to withdraw $5000 cash from bank that will be sent to my account and buy coins in bitcoin and send to someone using QR code. And I did the same. After 3 days bank send me email that my account has done suspicious activity and later I came to know that I got scammed or whatever. I have all proofs, chats with the person, receipts, emails. Now what should I do

Answer (score 4):

You were scammed. Your 5000$ are gone, and the payment into your bank account will be revoked or otherwise become invalid.

Contact the police and your bank, and learn from it.